# In R, how can I use a quoting function inside another function?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I am trying to figure out why `fun1()` works but `fun2()` throws an error.  I think it has something to do with the way in which `rlang` handles the quoting/unquoting of the `x` variable, but I'm not really sure.  This is a toy example.  I am trying to create a wrapper around several other custom quoting functions.

```
fun1 <- function(df, x, ...){
    x_var <- rlang::enquo(x)
    x_name <- rlang::ensym(x)
    
  out <- df%>%
         dplyr::group_by(...)%>%
         dplyr::summarise(!!x_name:=sum(!!x_var, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
         dplyr::ungroup()%>%
         data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   return(out)      
}

fun2 <- function(df, x, ...){
  out2 <- fun1(df = df, x=x, ...)
return(out2)
}

fun1(df = head(mtcars), x = mpg, cyl, disp, hp)

`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl', 'disp'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
  cyl disp  hp  mpg
1   4  108  93 22.8
2   6  160 110 42.0
3   6  225 105 18.1
4   6  258 110 21.4
5   8  360 175 18.7

fun2(df = head(mtcars), x = mpg, cyl, disp, hp)

Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `x`.
i `x = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.
x only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables
i The error occurred in group 1: cyl = 4, disp = 108, hp = 93.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I did check `rlang::last_error()` and `rlang::last_trace()`, but that did not help me figure out the issue.

Comment: I edited it.  I'm still fairly new to using dots, so I wasn't sure about syntax.  However, error is the same either way.

Comment: In `fun1`, you don't need `enquo` or `ensym`. You can instead do `dplyr::summarise({{x}} := sum({{x}}, na.rm = TRUE)) `.

Comment: @epi10 A good alternative for reducing code.  However, still need TarJae's answer to work.

Comment: Yes, my suggestion wasn't intended to address the error you were getting.

Comment: Also, if you want to return a standard R data frame (rather than a tibble), you can do `%>% as.data.frame`, rather than `%>% data.frame(., stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. `stringsAsFactors` is already FALSE by default in R 4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `{{}}` for column names:

```
fun2 <- function(df, x, ...){
  out2 <- fun1(df = df, x={{x}}, ...)
  return(out2)
}
```

```
  cyl disp  hp  mpg
1   4  108  93 22.8
2   6  160 110 42.0
3   6  225 105 18.1
4   6  258 110 21.4
5   8  360 175 18.7
```

Comment: Jeez so simple...yet I would never have guessed that! Thank you TarJae! Could you elaborate your answer a little more as to the philosophy behind {{}}.  It would help me and perhaps others who come here for a similar solution.

Comment: You can directly get access to a specific column of a dataframe by using double curly braces `{{...}}` around the desired column name in the function body, Please have a look here <https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/06/curly-curly-the-successor-of-bang-bang/> for deeper insight!

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much TarJae!